# Development to production, how to move a development site from http + dev.example.com to a production site https + example.com?

Tags: subdomains, https, http, development-strategy, production

I'm in a somewhat odd development situation where I need to develop a WP site at `http://dev.example.com/` and then make it live at `https://example.com/`.

The summary is:

1. Develop on `http`, publish on `https`
2. Develop on `dev.example.com`, publish on `example.com`

What should be done on the WP side of things? Is it as simple as updating the db replacing all occurences of `http://dev.example.com` to `https://example.com`?

What about wp-config.php?

I'm aware that plugins will probably have their own options that need updating. I'm mainly concerned about the core requirements. Media library links comes to mind.

Heck, maybe there's even a plugin that will do this for me? Or maybe development should be started in a specific way / or with a specific plugin?

I'm an experienced developer, but new to the WP-side of things. I'm very comfortable around the linux/db command line. I'm mainly looking for the general outline, but feel free to be as specific as you like. Every bit of info will help me sleep better at night.

Comment: we using https://de.wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/ for such stuff, saves us alot of work and must stuff work

Comment: Yes, I agree with @StefanBD, the Duplicator plugin is a pretty robust solution, we use it at our company with basically every website we publish. It takes care of every situation you mentioned in your question in very straightforward steps.

Comment: Good stuff, thank you both for the info. I'll leave the question up in hopes that someone happens along that can give me a technical answer of what needs to actually happen. e.g. *edit these db entries, update your wp-config.php, update your .htaccess*, etc.

Comment: i think the wp-site url in the wp_config and also the url in settings. After you should update 1 time the perm links in options and it should update the db and the .htaccess.

Comment: for the rest i would do a string replace in the mysql dump

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll try to outline the fundamental steps — your mileage might vary, depending on your actual setup. I tend to manage WordPress deployments in an automated manner (e.g. Ansible), so I have a preference for command-line scripts and config files.

1. Define the home and site url in the `wp-config.php` file of your production environment (the one on HTTPS):

```
define( 'WP_HOME', 'https://example.com/' );
define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'https://example.com/' );
```

These have precedence over the corresponding settings (**WordPress Address (URL)** and **Site Address (URL)**) in your **Settings** → **General** screen. Having them in `wp-config.php` also ensures they're instantly and correctly setup at deploy time.

2. Copy over your database (I do this via the mysql command line utility).
3. Copy over all files in your `wp-content` folder (including uploads).
4. Use WP CLI to search and replace URLs across the whole database:

```
wp search-replace 'http://example.com' 'https://example.com'
```

That's basically it for WordPress itself. Finally just make sure your web server is redirecting all traffic from http to https.

Comment: Great answer, exactly what I was looking for. Question about `wp cli`, how does it know which site you're targeting? Do you have to `cd` to the site directory first? I checked the docs, but it was unclear.

Comment: You can either `cd` into your site root directory (where `wp-config.php` is, by default), or run it from everywhere and specify your WordPress path with the `--path` option. See [Global Parameters](https://make.wordpress.org/cli/handbook/references/config/#global-parameters).